# How to transmute a flattened tensor/array back to original size while keeping specific order

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a flattened pytorch tensor that represents the indices for reverting a MaxPool2d operation, after getting the gradients for the backwards pass. The issue is that the size changes based on the kernel_size and the original input height/width before the MaxPool forward pass.
For example, lets say I have an input of size 2x4 with a kernel_size of 2x2 (kernel always square, and stride always same as kernel):

`input1 = tensor([[1,2,5,6], [3,4,7,8]])`
For input1, after the forward pass, the indices will be [3,3](indexing from 0).
In the backwards pass, I then, after flattening and adding the gradient, end up with a tensor like this:
tensor([0,0,0,(gradient of 4),0,0,0,(gradient of 8)])

The issue is that I now need to transform the tensor back into the original shape while keeping the number order. Using something simple like tensor.view(input_height,input_width) doesn't work because the order of the numbers is messed up:
`input1.view(2,4) = tensor([[1,2,3,4],  [5,6,7,8]])`

I've tried things like chunking it into groups of input_height/input_width but then I have issues making it work for different sizes. I think there is an easy solution and I just lack the pytorch or numpy skills to figure it out :(

Edit:
Ok so I've tried `input1.view(2,4)` which as I've explained doesn't have the right order. And getting the right order isn't possible through permute or similar functions. I've tried chunking this way:
`input1.view(-1, 2)` which splits the tensor into chunks of 2, but then I can't stack them back up properly into multiple columns. I've searched everywhere and I don't know how to progress. I've even (to no avail) asked chatGPT lol.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to rearrange the flattened tensor back into the original shape while keeping the order:

```py
import torch

flattened = torch.tensor([0,0,0,4,0,0,0,8]) # flattened tensor
kernel_size = 2
input_h = 2  
input_w = 4

unflatten = []
for i in range(0, len(flattened), input_w):
    unflatten.append(flattened[i:i+input_w])

result = torch.stack(unflatten)
print(result)
```

The key ideas:

- Iterate over the flattened tensor in chunks of size `input_w` (the original input width)
- Append those chunks as separate tensors to create a list
- Stack that list back into a 2D tensor

This takes advantage of slicing the flattened tensor and stitching together the pieces.

The output with the example data is:

```
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 8]])
```